# Compilation errors after inserting a tFTPGet componatn

Tags: compiler-errors, talend

I've a Talend (5.6.1) job which works fine.
Basically, it get files from a local drive and put them into Salesforce.

Now, the change is that I cannot continue to store these files locally.
They are now shared by a FTP server.

So, I've added a tFTPConnection componant (works fine) and somewhere in my job I want to add a tFTPGet to put the files in a local directory before to push them to Salesforce.

Actually, filename are made in a tMap and converted one by one in a tJavaRow component, so I have:

```
tMap -> tJavaRow (convert files) -> tSalesforceOutput (push to Salesforce)
```

Before this tMap, I've some tasks to filter the valid rows and push the bad ones in a tFileOutputDelimited.

So, if I try to put a tFTPGet before the tJavaRow to get the needed file, all the tFileOutputDelimited of the same flow generate compilation errors:

```
tFileOutputDelimited_7 canot be resolved as a variable
nb_line_tFileOutputDelimited_7 canot be resolved
fileName_tFileOutputDelimited_7 canot be resolved
```

These errors disapear if I remove the tFTPGet.
As I cannot understand why, any idea are welcome.

Best regards,
Fred

Comment: Can you please put your tFTPGet settings ?

Comment: Hi,

I don't think it comes from the tFTPGet settings.
I've just replaced the tFTPGet by a tRunJob and put my tFTPConnection and tFTPGet in the subjob and it works fine.

Regards,
Fred